# Regular expression to extract part of a string from name and path

Tags: regex, string

I need to extract part of a string in a file path like the following:

```
Z:\ACB_TACC\9236747171 22 TACC.ACM
Z:\ACB_TACC\Machine1\9236748316_TACC.ACM
```

in both cases, i Need to extract the string between the last \ character and the last number character before TACC.ACM or _TACC.ACM, I mean, in the forst case: 
9236747171 22
in the second case:
9236748316

How can I do that with a Regular Expression?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this,

```
\\([^\\]*?)(?=[_ ]?TACC\.ACM$)
```

or

```
(?<=\\)[^\\]*?(?=[ _]?TACC\.ACM$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/mL5eD8/1)

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, you can use `(\d|\s)*\d(?!.*\\)`. This means match 0 or more digits or whitespace characters followed by a digit (so at least 1 digit altogether) such that there are no `\` chracters after the match anywhere in the string. If you use a regex implementation that supports positive lookbehind you could add that as a condition to have the `\` before the match.

```js
var re = /(\d|\s)*\d(?!.*\\)/;
alert('Z:\\ACB_TACC\\9236747171 22 TACC.ACM'.match(re)[0]);
alert('Z:\\ACB_TACC\\Machine1\\9236748316_TACC.ACM'.match(re)[0]);
```